# Setting the Charset on mysql column

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Hello I am trying to set the charset on my column due to the fact we have a database with different charsets on different tables. Here is my code that is failing.

```
CREATE TABLE `ax_np_rain_accounts`(  
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`service_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`type_id` INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`date_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`is_processed` TINYINT(1),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX (`service_id`),
INDEX (`date_created`),
FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `ax_services`(`ServiceId`)  CHARACTER 
SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `ax_np_transaction_types`(`id`) CHARACTER 
SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHARACTER SET` should be applied on the column definition, not the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

`CHARACTER SET` does not apply to `INT` datatype, only variants of `CHAR` and `TEXT` and `ENUM`.

The `(2)` means nothing in `INT(2)`; perhaps you should use `TINYINT UNSIGNED`?

A *table* can have a *default* `CHARACTER SET`.  This setting applies to any char/text columns for which you do not explicitly set the charset.

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    a VARCHAR(9) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    b VARCHAR(9) CHARACTER SET latin1,
    c VARCHAR(9)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET big5;
```

`c` will be implicitly `big5`; a will be explicitly `utf8`; `b` will be `latin1`.

When `JOINing` two tables on a char/text column, be sure to have the *same* `CHARACTER SET` *and* `COLLATION` declared (explicitly or implicitly).  Otherwise, performance is likely to suffer.

Comment: I have been shown this before don't know what I was thinking. Thanks for the answer.